# LINQ Conditionally Add Join

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ query where I'm trying to return data from 2 tables, but the tables that I join are conditional.

This is what I'd like to do:

```
if (teamType == "A"){
    var query = from foo in context.People
                join foo2 in context.PeopleExtendedInfoA
                select foo;
}
else {
    var query = from foo in context.People
                join foo2 in context.PeopleExtendedInfoB
                select foo;
}
```

Then later on I'm filtering the query down even further.  I obviously can't set it up this way because I won't be able to access "query" outside the if block, but it shows what I'm trying to do.  This is an example of what I'm trying to do later on with the query:

```
if (state != null)
{
     query = query.Where(p => p.State == state);
}

if (query != null) {
   var queryFinal = from foo in query
         select new PeopleGrid()
         {
              Name = foo.Name,
              Address = foo.Address,
              Hobby = foo2.Hobby
         }
}
```

What I'm trying to return is all the data from table foo and then one field from the joined table, but depending on the logic, the joined table will differ.  Both PeopleExtendedInfoA and PeopleExtendedInfoB both have the columb 'Hobby', but I have no way to access 'Hobby' from the joined table and that's the only field I need from the joined table.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Does `PeopleExtendedInfoA` and `PeopleExtendedInfoB` inherits from the same base class? You could create a `IQueryable<BaseClass>` and let the linq provider solve it for you when you add the join. For sample:

```
IQueryable<BasePeople> basePeople;
if (teamType == "A")
   basePeople = context.PeopleExtendedInfoA;
else
   basePeople = context.PeopleExtendedInfoB;

var query = from foo in context.People
            join foo2 in basePeople on foo.Id equals foo2.PeopleId
            select new PeopleGrid()
            {
              Name = foo.Name,
              Address = foo.Address,
              Hobby = foo2.Hobby
            };
```

Comment: OP doesn't specify if this is `Linq-to-Objects/SQL/Entities`, but I don't think this type of query works in some of the db backed Linq providers (at least older versions, not sure about newer ones).

Comment: No, PeopleExtendedInfoA and PeopleExtendedInfoB are separate classes and are actually de-normalized.  A record in the People class has 1 matching record in either PeopleExtendedInfoA OR PeopleExtendedInfoB, depending on their "Team".  All I need to get out of PeopleExtendedInfoA and/or PeopleExtendedInfoB is just one field called "Hobby".  Sorry if the design doesn't make sense in my example, I promise it makes sense in my real world application.

Comment: @Ocelot20 Many query providers actually *do* support inheritance on entities and allow queries to be covariant.  You'd need to do some work to set up the inheritance, but it's at least plausible that it would be supported.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying.  It is Linq to Entities.

Comment: @Servy: True, but last time I played with EF inheritance it was definitely limited in the types of queries it could perform well (I've heard it's since been improved, not sure how much). Wanted to make a note of it since `Linq-to-SQL` definitely wouldn't support it. So @user3653675, how is it currently structured in your db?

Comment: PeopleExtendedInfoA and B do not inherit from any class in my situation.  It's a strange one and on the surface seems like it should be inheriting from the same base class, but it's not.  The example I gave is a simplified version of the problem I'm having.  I could tell you the exact situation and problem I'm having, but then I'd have to...well you know.  I solved my problem and posted it as an answer, in case anybody is wondering.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
 var queryFinal = from foo in query
                  where foo.State == state !=null ? state : foo.State
         select new PeopleGrid()
         {
              Name = foo.Name,
              Address = foo.Address,
              Hobby = foo2.Hobby
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query into an intermediate type that holds the relevant fields, or if the query is simple enough you can use anonymous types as seen below. The important part is that the `Join` calls both have the same return types (`{ p.Name, a.Hobby }` and `{ p.Name, b.Hobby }` will both be the same anon type).

```
var baseQuery = context.People;

var joined = type == "A" ?
    baseQuery.Join(PeopleExtendedInfoA,
        p => p.Id,
        a => a.PeopleId,
        (p, a) => new { p, a.Hobby }) :
    baseQuery.Join(PeopleExtendedInfoB,
        p => p.Id,
        b => b.PeopleId,
        (p, b) => new { p, b.Hobby });

var result = joined.Select(x => new
    {
        x.p.Name,
        x.p.Address,
        // etc.
        x.Hobby
    };
```

Comment: Thanks.  This idea seems like it may work best, especially since I only need one field from PeopleExtendedInfoA or PeopleExtendedInfoB and they are the same type/name.  Is there any way of doing it without having to declare all the fields?  The fields being returned that are needed from "People" are quite a few, so I'm trying to reduce duplicate/unnecessary code.  For example can I do something like: (p, a) => new { p, a.Hobby })  Where p is all fields in that table and only return Hobby from table a?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do that (see my update above). Although I suggest naming things a bit better than my example for some added clarity.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up doing something similar but I just joined on the result query that way I could still do my normal filtering on the baseQuery and not have to worry about the compiler complaining about different types.

Comment: Not sure I follow. This solution doesn't limit you from filtering on `baseQuery`, it's just an example of the `Join` part.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Thanks everyone for all the replies, it got my brain working again and gave me some new ideas (even though I didn't directly take any of them)  I realize I needed to do the join at the very end instead of the beginning that way I don't have to deal with filtering on different types. This is what I did:

```
var query = from foo in context.People
            select foo;

if (state != null)
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.State == state);
}

if (query != null) {
   if (teamType == "A")
   {
      var queryFinal = from foo in query
                       join foo2 in context.PeopleExtendedInfoA
      select new PeopleGrid()
      {
          Name = foo.Name,
          Address = foo.Address,
          Hobby = foo2.Hobby
      }
   }
   else
   {
      var queryFinal = from foo in query
                       join foo2 in context.PeopleExtendedInfoB
      select new PeopleGrid()
      {
          Name = foo.Name,
          Address = foo.Address,
          Hobby = foo2.Hobby
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This still suffers from the problem your original question stated in that `queryFinal` can't be used outside the if/else blocks. Are you returning `queryFinal` immediately in both cases or something? Also, `query` essentially *can't* be null, so the null check isn't necessary.

Comment: Yes, PeopleGrid is being returned right after this code ends.  Sorry for not making that clear.  There are a bunch of if/else blocks, but I put them before queryFinal.