# Linq query to return different types of collections conditioanlly

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

What is the best way to bring back collection of different types using Linq.
I have chats table that houses different types of chat messages:

- pure text
- image
- video

the columns of the table are:

- Id
- senderId (who sent the chat message)
- string (for text chat messages)
- image/video url (for image or video url)
- type (1 for text, 2 for image and 3 for video)
- created_date (datetime of the chat added)

I am returning that info from a view model:

```
var query = _context.Chats.Select(c => new ChatViewModel {
  // 
});
```

When the user sends video message, I want to have more information to bring back like (the url to the 1st frame image of the video, the length in seconds).

I don't knwo how and where to house those extra video info? I can add 2 Nullable extra columns specifically for when the row is video, but as you know it is a very ugly choice.

Or I can add a whole new table for those 2 columns, but then how would I conditionally join to this table when the row is a video type? 
Do I do a left outer join to this table (cross join in chained-syntax Linq)? What if I also decide to move the image extra info to its own table, would that be other left outer join to that too?

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23744305/1019042) suggests to use a base class to have an effect like:

```
IQueryable<BasePeople> basePeople;
if (teamType == "A")
   basePeople = context.PeopleExtendedInfoA;
else
   basePeople = context.PeopleExtendedInfoB;
```

and then join to that base class, but in that example PeopleExtendedInfoA and PeopleExtendedInfoB are of the same type whereas my video type is different to the other 2 types (text and image).

Please note: the created date order of the chats returned must be in consideration when rows are returned from server.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first reaction is to return the URL and duration as a child table.  If the message is not a video message, there would be no rows in the child table.

Comment: thx for taking the time. How would you conditionally write that in linq to that video child table? What if I also decide to have image child table too?

Comment: I think Brian is right, if you need a table for image data then...you add it. A simple `LEFT JOIN` or  separate query when building viewmodel.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with the actual LINQ syntax - I've never used that outside of some **very** simple tutorials.  My answer was based purely on database design principles.